# Erlang rebar project in intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, erlang, rebar

How I can create a rebar project and import it in intellij?

I'm following this guide [Getting Started with Erlang (intellij)](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/getting-started-with-erlang.html#Getting_started_with_Erlang-13-chapter), but when i try to import the rebar project the whole folder is imported ([project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/svSDU.png)).

Probably i didn't quite understand how to create a rebar project (`rebar create-app appid=WEBerlServer`)

Comment: Just FYI, `rebar` is deprecated. You should be using `rebar3`.

Comment: thanks, this is my first time using erlang

Comment: https://riptutorial.com/erlang/example/15671/bootstrapping-a-new-erlang-project